# How to check successive object presence elegantly

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to write this more elegantly?

```
if ("a" in obj && "b" in obj.a && "c" in obj.a.b)
```

instead of checking for existence on each stage of the object?

If I do `if ("c" in obj.a.b)` this will give error if `a` or `b` doesn't exist.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: if your runtime supports it you can use the optional chaining `if ("c" in (obj?.a?.b ?? {}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Old way

```
if (obj.a && obj.a.b && obj.a.b.c) {
  // do something
}
```

### New way

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
if (obj.a?.b?.c) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always found the lodash [_.has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has) and [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) functions very powerful, you can access deeply nested values in objects without a lot of code to check the path exists.

For example:

```js
const obj = { a: { b: { c: 42 }}};

if (_.has(obj, "a.b.c")) {
    console.log("Path exists");
}

// Safe to access, will return undefined if path does not exist...
console.log("Path value:", _.get(obj, "a.b.c"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### pluckDeep helper function

```
function pluckDeep(key) {

   return function(obj) {

        return key.split('.').reduce((accum, key) => {
            return accum[key]
        }, obj);

   }

}

const obj = { a: { b: { c: 42 }}};


if (pluckDeep('a.b.c')(obj)) {
  // do something
}
```

This curried function can determine if a property exist by using the first parameter of the pluckDeep function.